# How to Put different watermarks on even an odd pages using xwatermark?

Tags: tikz-pgf, hyperref, pdfpages, xwatermark

I want to get a transparent foreground watermark that will be different for even and odd pages and which does not render the underlying content, such as text and images, is invalid. Is it possible?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true, %set true if you want colored links
    linktoc=all,     %set to all if you want both sections and subsections linked
    linkcolor=blue,  %choose some color if you want links to stand out
}

\newsavebox\mybox
\savebox\mybox{\tikz[color=red,opacity=0.3]\node{BSFU};}
\newwatermark*[
  allpages,
  angle=45,
  scale=12,
  xpos=-20,
  ypos=15
]{\usebox\mybox}
\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\mybox}]{output}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It appears that the `xwatermark` package has options `oddpages` and `evenpages` in place of `` all pages, which feels like exactly what you want. See the doc for more information.

Comment: @Symbol1 Thank you very much for your information, but I have a little doubt about the different text which I have to put for even-odd pages, How?

Comment: I meant to say something like `\newwatermark[oddpages]{odd page watermark}
\newwatermark[evenpages]{even page watermark}` but for now the version of `xwatermark` I have does not compile. Will comeback later

Comment: @Symbol1 xwatermark is incompatible with a current LaTeX as  it uses the catoptions package.

Comment: TY, good to know. Shall I suggest OP using `eso-pic`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer more like `xwatermark` is incompatible with LaTeX due to the `catoptions` usage, and in recent versions of LaTeX this incompatibility results in errors, while previously it just resulted in unexpected behaviour in some cases.

Comment: @Symbol1 I use either eso-pic or directly the shipout hooks for watermarks.

Comment: That's a strong endorsement that eso-pic is a good package. I have always been wondering what top user's document look like.

Answer (score 2):

The following would use LaTeX's builtin shipout hooks to place two different boxes for your watermark, based on the `page`-counter being even or odd.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\AddToHook{shipout/foreground}
  {%
    \put(0.5\paperwidth,-0.5\paperheight){\mywatermark}%
  }
\newcommand*\mywatermark
  {%
    \ifodd\value{page}%
      \usebox\mywatermarkboxODD
    \else
      \usebox\mywatermarkboxEVEN
    \fi
  }
\newsavebox\mywatermarkboxEVEN
\newsavebox\mywatermarkboxODD
\tikzset{mywatermark/.style={color=red,opacity=0.3,font=\huge,rotate=#1}}
\AtBeginDocument
  {%
    \sbox\mywatermarkboxODD
      {\makebox[0pt]{\tikz\node[mywatermark=45]{BSFU};}}%
    \sbox\mywatermarkboxEVEN
      {\makebox[0pt]{\tikz\node[mywatermark=-45]{BSFU};}}%
  }

\usepackage{duckuments}

\begin{document}
\duckument
\end{document}
```

[image]